# In System Logs what does the false|true mean for Variables

Tags: apex, debugging, developer-console, code, logging

There's a lot I don't understand about the Execution Logs from Salesforce. Maybe some of it is just my limited programming experience (Apex mostly, smattering of Python). I feel like there must be more clues in the Logs than I'm picking up on.

What does the false|true mean in the following example?

> 20:56:40:585 VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN [9]|LeadUtility.Group_Name|String|false|true

I see this pair for new Variables, and true|false for Collections and sObjects—do they tell us anything useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN event has the following fields in order: Line number, variable name, type, a value that indicates if the variable can be referenced, and a value that indicates if the variable is static.

So, the false here means that it can't be referenced and true means it is static.

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_system_log_console.htm

Comment: That page is great! Guess it pays to re-read the Apex guide annually...

Answer (score 2):

Line number, variable name, type, a value that indicates if the variable can be referenced, and a value that indicates if the variable is static

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_system_log_console.htm